# UIKit vs ImageMagick for compressing JPEGs

Tags: ios, image-processing, uikit, imagemagick, jpeg

I am thinking of switching to ImageMagick to get better performance on jpeg compression on my iOS app. When I say performance, I mean a better image for the same amount of quality setting, and possibly a smaller image in terms of filesize. Does anyone have any experience comparing the two and is it a worthwhile exercise? Samples?

The UIKit JPEG stuff aren't that great and image sizes are still quite large. I can't find any other libraries I can use with iOS either. Any wisdom is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Its the JPEG standard that affects the tradeoff between image size and quality - it has nothing to do with the frameword or app that does it. So if you compress a JPEG on iOS with  some "quality" setting, the image size will be identical if you use ImageMagik. That said, one issue is that Apple uses a different "quality" scale than does say libjpg.

But, in the end, if you reduce the quality to some low number using Preview, iOS, ImageMagick, and it seems somewhat pixelated, then the file size will be the same. That's how the JPEG standard works.

Comment: So I've done lots of reading last few days about JPEG compression, which is the basis of my question. Photoshop, for example, at 60% quality achieves better 'looking' JPEGs than some other jpeg libraries around. The reason for this is the loss of quality can be derived with any number of complex paramaters and calculated in an open-ended way, like subsampling ratios etc. So I guess what I wanted to know was if ImageMagick would help me achieve better compression because UIKit only lets you give an umbrella quality figure. I hope that makes some sense. I might be wrong!!!

Comment: You could be correct. There are definitely several parameters that can be adjusted. So if photoshop creates a better looking image given the outputted file size, does it analyze the image in play first? I could believe for different kinds of images different sets of parameters could make a difference. But with imagemagik you would have to determine those,no? Perhaps you should take some of your images and experiment. I've used libjpeg to shrink tiffs in code and all I ever did was set the single quality number.